# Issues encounter when implementing Docker and Nginx

Tags: asp.net-mvc, docker, nginx, openid-connect

*I've deliberately remove sensitive information in the codes and image*

I'm facing couple of issues with setting up using `Docker` and `Nginx`. My solutions/service have been dockizer successfully but the services are unable to communicate via the `Nginx`.

I've a docker that contains 3 services which are my solutions.

- `Auth Service`; to authentication user when logging in using OpenID Connect
- `Portal Service`; authenticated user to access various views
- `API Service`; an API to Get or Post based on user request.

Also to note `Nginx` is also a service in my Docker. And all my services the ports are expose correctly

Details of the set up as follows:

- `Auth Service` is in a reverse proxy with server name as id-local..com
- `Portal Service` is in a reverse proxy with the server name as app-
  local..com
- `API Service` is an API gateway share the same server name as Portal Service; app-local..com
- Both servers are running with SSL and HTTP2; *I've omit out SSL related cert*.
- Both servers are actually the same IP address as they are sit on the same PC. Do note that the port number in the `Nginx` might be wrong as I was following a tutorial.

**Issue 1** User has log in successfully via `Auth Service` and `Auth Service` shall re-direct to my `Portal Service` via `Nginx`. But instead I encounter an issue whereby `Portal Service` is unable to get the `Auth Service`'s Discovery EndPoint.

It is also to note that Auth Service; once user log in successfully, the service shall generate two cookies; `idsrv.session` and `an external .net cookies`. *In IIS, those two cookies are to be shared throughout the services.* The Portal Service, requires the metadata of Auth Service in order to generate a JWT cookies.

[Screenshot for the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ojHv.png)

Error log:

```
Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://app-local..com:44343/favicon.ico - -

Executing endpoint '..Web.Controllers.ErrorController.Route (..Web)'

Route matched with {action = "Route", controller = "Error"}. Executing controller action with signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult Route(System.String) on controller ..Web.Controllers.ErrorController (..Web).

Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.

[INF]  Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.

[INF]  Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ([]).

[INF]  Executed action ..Web.Controllers.ErrorController.Route (.Web) in 3.2872ms

[INF]  Executed endpoint '..Web.Controllers.ErrorController.Route (.Web)'

[ERR]  An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://id-local..com:5200/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
  ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://id-local..com:5200/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
  ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Connection refused (id-local..com:5200)
  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (111): Connection refused
    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|283_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.DefaultConnectAsync(SocketsHttpConnectionContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(Func`3 callback, DnsEndPoint endPoint, HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(Func`3 callback, DnsEndPoint endPoint, HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
    at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel)
    at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleChallengeAsyncInternal(AuthenticationProperties properties)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.ChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAlwaysRunResultFilters>g__Awaited|26_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
    at WebMarkupMin.AspNetCore3.WebMarkupMinMiddleware.ProcessAsync(HttpContext context, Boolean useMinification, Boolean useCompression)
    at WebMarkupMin.AspNetCore3.WebMarkupMinMiddleware.ProcessAsync(HttpContext context, Boolean useMinification, Boolean useCompression)
    at WebMarkupMin.AspNetCore3.WebMarkupMinMiddlewareBase.Invoke(HttpContext context)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.StatusCodePagesExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<<UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute>b__0>d.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.StatusCodePagesMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)366
[INF]  Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://app-local..com:44343/favicon.ico - - - 500 - text/plain 8.9ms
```

Part of `Nginx` Config file

```
upstream auth 
{
    server authservice:5001;
}
upstream portal
{ 
    server portalservice:5010;
}

server 
{        
    listen 44343 http2 ssl;

    server_name id-local.com;    

    location /
    {
        proxy_pass         http://auth;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host:44343;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
}

server 
{        
    listen 44343 http2 ssl;

    server_name app-local.com;    

    location /
    {
        proxy_pass         http://portal;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host:44343;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name:44343;
        proxy_buffer_size           128k;
        proxy_buffers               4 256k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size     256k;
    }
}
```

**Issue 2** I tried to use `Nginx` as API gateway for `API Service`. And encounter another problem.

Error log

```
"GET /api/v1 HTTP/2.0" 502 559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
[error] 34#34: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 123.456.112.1, server: app-local..com, request: "GET /api/v1 HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://123.456.112.6:5020/api/v1", host: "app-local.com:5200"
```

Part of `Nginx` Config file

```
upstream api 
{ 
    server apiservice:5020;
}
server 
{        
    listen 44343 http2 ssl;

    server_name app-local.com;    
    #include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
            
    location /api/v1
    {
         proxy_pass         http://api/api/v1;
         proxy_redirect     off;
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
         proxy_set_header   Host $host:44343;
         proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
         proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name:44343;
         proxy_buffer_size           128k;
         proxy_buffers               4 256k;
         proxy_busy_buffers_size     256k;
     }
 }
```

From the error, it seems like `Nginx` is unable to access the `API Service`'s container. What is puzzling; when using Postman, I am able to get the data via `http://localhost:5020/api/v1`.

Part of `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.9'

    services:
      nginxservice:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: 
        depends_on:
          - authservice
        ports:
          - "5200:44343"

      apiservice:
        image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: 
        environment:
          - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
          - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
        ports:
          - 5020:80

    portalservice:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: 
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:5010
    ports:
      - 5010:5010

  authservice:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: 
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:5001
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5001:5001
```

Appreciated everyone to help

***EDIT**: 14 Jul 2021: To add the more details especially on the setup of the services and the server name.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things that caught my eye.

- Are you intending to use SSL or not? Did you omit the SSL cert / key configuration while putting it up here? Either way, `http://app-local..com:44343` seems to be contradicting the endpoint in your image which has the `id-local` accessed via https.
- You seem to have configured `id-local.com` to be listening on port `44343`. Are you configuring it correctly in your oidc client application? (can't really see from the screenshot as some parts of the URL is hidden)
- You seem to indicate that the user was successfully logged in. I would assume there's a cookie involved in this. Can you check if the cookie is being set for correct domain and therefore subsequent requests to your auth service actually recieves the cookie back?

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. For point 1, Yes I'm using SSL and HTTP2 as I intend to use gRPC too. Hence I did omit out the SSL Cert/key on purpose (I'm not sure is create any risk) and the port is expose is 5200. point 2, I was following the tutorial so I'm not sure is my port number handle correct. Let me investigate on my end. point 3, yes there are cookies which I've re-edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolve the issue. The problem is *drum rolls* due to the mapping of the expose port number in Nginx Service.

It seems that for any docker services (correct me if I'm wrong), the mapping of the expose port number and the internal container's port number must be the same.

Hence instead of `"5200:44343"`, it should be `"44343:44343"`

Comment: If it helps we have quite a few resources at Curity in our [API Gateway Guides](https://curity.io/resources/guides/) since our standard setup is to run behind a reverse proxy. This [article + Docker compose example](https://curity.io/resources/learn/implementing-dynamic-user-routing/) may give you something to compare against.